# How to estimate the highest power of 2 in the partial sum of 2-adic $\log(-1)$ (i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2^i}{i}$)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, elementary-proofs, p-adic-numbers

**The estimate I wanna get is $$v_2(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2^i}{i})\geq\min_{t\geq n+1}\{t-v_2(t)\}\tag{*}$$**
where $v_2$ is the 2-adic valuation, that is the highest power of 2 defined on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Set $$S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2^i}{i}.$$

One knows that $$\log(-1)=\log(1+(-2))\equiv -\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2^i}{i}+\text{multiples of }2^{n+1}\equiv -\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2^i}{i}\mod 2^{n+1}$$
so we have$$ 0=2\log(-1)\equiv-2S_n\equiv-2S_{n-1}\mod 2^{n+1}  $$
which means $$ v_2(2S_{n-1})\geq n+1.  $$

So we might get $v_2(S_n)\geq n+1$.

But I still get trouble showing the inequility (*).

Comment: in your main formula you have sum of multiples $2^{t- v_2(t)}$ for $t>n$ not multiples of $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Since the $2$-adic log of $-1$ is $0$, just write $\sum_{i = 1}^n 2^i/i$ as $-\sum_{i\geq n+1} 2^i/i$ and use the non-Archimedean triangle inequality on the second series. Your desired lower bound falls out right away.

Comment: @PavelKozlov: Well I got it, thx!

Comment: @KConrad: Although it's not that elementary as the way i wanted. Anyway thx!

Comment: The calculation you presented implies $\sum_{i\geq 1} 2^i/i = 0$ by letting $n\to \infty$, so the solution I described is not much more elementary than what you were doing.